# How to find and replace in linux on a large file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian, sed

Oh, hi;

So I've got this big json file and I'm trying to find and replace a few things but when I've used sed I get an error and I need a sed or awk string to find and replace it, without getting an error.

- prajwal

Current:

```
{"telephone_numbers":["1-
```

Future:

```
{"telephone_numbers":["+1-
```

This is the command i tried and the error i got.

```
sed -i 's/{"telephone_numbers":["1-/{"telephone_numbers":["+1-/g' output.json
sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `sed` command you used

```
s/{"telephone_numbers":["1-/{"telephone_numbers":["+1-/g
```

`[` in the pattern is interpreted as the beginning of a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (e.g. `[abc]` or `[a-z]`). There is no closing `]` and the whole logic breaks.

But you don't want character sets in the first place, you want literal `[` characters. Escape them with `\`.

Strictly you need to escape the first one and you may or may not escape the second one. This is because character sets belong to regular expressions. In `s/pattern/replacement/` the pattern is parsed as a regular expression but the replacement is not. Your second `[` is supposed to be in the replacement where unescaped `[` is not special. The fixed command will be:

```
sed -i 's/{"telephone_numbers":\["1-/{"telephone_numbers":["+1-/g' output.json
```

Comment: didn't work.i just did it and there is literally 0 changes on the file.

Comment: @PrajwalKoirala In my Debian 10 the command `sed 's/{"telephone_numbers":\["1-/{"telephone_numbers":["+1-/g'` does change your "current" string to the "future" one. Are the strings really representative to what you're trying to do?

Comment: ```sed 's/{"telephone_numbers":\["1-/{"telephone_numbers":["+1-/g' output.json
sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX```

Comment: @PrajwalKoirala Your file apparently is not a text file in terms of POSIX. `sed` works with lines; some implementations can work with very long lines, but a "line" that exceeds `INT_MAX` is quite a big deal. Do you keep binary blobs in the file? What `sed` implementation do you use? GNU `sed` [claims it can take as much as `malloc()` allows](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-GNU-extensions_002c-unlimited-line-length). Frankly this is a different issue than your original `unterminated 's' command`. This site works best in the "one issue - one question" scheme.

Comment: It's just a json. (mongo output)
no binary;
sed (GNU sed) 4.7;

Comment: @PrajwalKoirala Not my expertise, but it seems JSON does not rely on newlines, so text processing tools may not work. You should probably use a specialized tool. Currently I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I found a `.go` script that does this.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
        "strings"
)

func visit(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {

        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        if !!fi.IsDir() {
                return nil //
        }

        matched, err := filepath.Match("*.json", fi.Name())

        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
                return err
        }

        if matched {
                read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }
                //fmt.Println(string(read))
                fmt.Println(path)

                newContents := strings.Replace(string(read), "1-", "+1-", -1)

                fmt.Println(newContents)

                err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, []byte(newContents), 0)
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }

        }

        return nil
}

func main() {
        err := filepath.Walk(".", visit)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}
```

Than build the file

```
go build main.go
```

Lets run the script

```
./main
```

This script works on almost any file size, and any file type.