# sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX

Tags: ubuntu, debian, sed

i am trying to sed and change something from a json file and i am getting this error.

- prajwal

```
sed -i 's/{"telephone_numbers":\["1-/{"telephone_numbers":["+1-/g' output.json
sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX
```

Comment: This should be raised with the person who [counseled](https://superuser.com/a/1575670/8672) this command.

Comment: Use `jq` to parse JSON.